# rmap functions are undefined

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, rhel

I'm making a Linux kernel device driver (Linux redhat 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). Whenever I attempt to use rmap functions, like `rmap_walk` or `vma_address`, the linker complains:

```
WARNING: "rmap_walk" [/root/my_dir/my_device.ko] undefined!
```

I'm building against the running kernel:

```
obj-m += my_device.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

I guess it's because those functions are not exported with `EXPORT_SYMBOL`. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: try using this function kallsyms_lookup_name

Comment: @c4f4t0r It's also not exported.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm making a Linux kernel device driver (Linux redhat
>   2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). Whenever I attempt to use rmap functions, like `rmap_walk` or `vma_address`, the linker
>   complains… I guess it's because those functions are not exported with
>   `EXPORT_SYMBOL`.

Regarding `rmap_walk` - there is no [`rmap_walk` in Linux 2.6.32](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.32&i=rmap_walk).

Regarding `vma_address`, you are right.

> Is there any workaround for that?

Yes, you can copy the [source code of `vma_address`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/rmap.c?v=2.6.32#L225) into your driver. `vma_address` does not call other functions, so this works.